# In Wordpress CMS, the controls under the WYSIWYG editor

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a wordpress plugin where it adds additional controls underneath the WYSIWYG editor when adding pages/posts.  But I don't know what keywords I'm supposed to google for to find relevant tutorials on how to do it.

Can someone provide me with resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [add_meta_box()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) - call it within a hooked `admin_init` function like so;

```
function my_custom_meta_box()
{
    add_meta_box(
        'my_meta_box_id',
        'My Meta Box Title',
        'my_meta_box_callback',
        'post', // either post, page or link,
        'normal', // position of the meta box,
        'high' // position priority
    );
}
add_action('admin_init', 'my_custom_meta_box');

function my_meta_box_callback()
{
    echo 'This is the content of my meta box!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the filter reference for hooks to add to the editor? [Plugin API/Filter Reference « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) There are lots of plugins that add controls to the editor: [WordPress › WordPress Plugins - TinyMCE](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=tinymce&sort=)

Comment: I just noticed a plugin that does what I want to do.  I see a page called editpage.php, and in that file are functions like <h3><?php _e('Real Estate - Property Information','greatrealestate'); ?></h3>.  Then it appears as a "form block" underneath the Page Revisions block.  What is this approach called and how can I learn to create my own "form blocks"?

Answer (score 0):

I've written a good tutorial on [adding WordPress Meta Boxes](http://farinspace.com/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-meta-box/) additionally check out my [WPalchemy Meta Box PHP Class](http://farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/) which will help you create meta boxes with ease.